# Force Wordpress https redirect before www redirect based on site address url

Tags: redirect, https

The default web address for a domain is:

```
https://www.example.com
```

If I set this as the 'Site Address (URL)' in Wordpress then it seems to take care of the necessary http -> https and non-www -> www redirection on it's own.

The problem is though is that Wordpress redirects the following first:

```
http://example.com to http://www.example.com
```

Before this one:

```
http://example.com to https://example.com
```

Which means that our [HSTS](https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/what-is-hsts-and-how-do-i-use-it/) preload status and eligibility is failing which we check [here](https://hstspreload.org).

We are needing to ensure that the https redirect happens BEFORE the www redirect.

---

I have no idea how best to do this but I would probably prefer some sort of theme function that hooks into the default functionality and modifies it accordingly.

I did try setting the default site address to `http://example.com` and then handling the https and www redirect in the .htaccess but this doesn't seem ideal and can get messy (plus I could only get the https redirect to work and not the www redirect afterwards).

Surely there must be plenty of other HSTS eligible Wordpress websites that use a default `https://www` start to the website?

Answer (score 1):

Just do it in your .htaccess, it will be alot simpler. The important thing is that the rules are **above** WordPress' rules. Setting **L** also states, that this shall be the last rule evaluated if a match was found

```
# Redirect to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: When I try this (which I had already tried), the site fails to load due to "too many redirects". I can get an https redirect to work in the `.htaccess` but it just doesn't like a subsequent www redirect for some reason.

Comment: @zigojacko Is WordPress set to https & www? Where is it redirecting you? This setup works in regular configuration, there might be something else that creates the many redirects

Comment: If I add the redirects in `.htaccess` then I am making the Wordpress settings address `http://example.com` but the actual address we want to use is `https://www.example.com` (and ideally this is what we would have set in the Wordpress settings). I think the issue with the 'too many redirects' is that when in settings, you've omitted the 'www', Wordpress by default will try and redirect any request to the non-www so with the www redirect in `.htaccess`, it's creating a redirect loop.

Comment: You need to set the URL in WordPress to `https://www.example.com` - why would you omit the www here?

Comment: 1. Because the whole issue is that if `https://www` exists in the Wordpress settings, then by default Wordpress is initiating the www redirect BEFORE the https redirect (which cannot happen for HSTS eligibility for subdomains) and 2. because we tried handling the 'www' redirect in the `.htaccess` file as per your suggestion (why would we try and redirect it if it exists as part of the address in the settings)?

Comment: I have just however found out that I can disable the automatic Wordpress redirection (like http/https and www based on the address settings) with this: `remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');`

Comment: If you place the redirects in your .htaccess like I showed, you do not need to worry about WordPress redirects - as long as the site URL is configured in the way that the manually inserted redirects work.

Comment: I've already done that (with the address in settings as `https://www.example.com`) and the 'www' redirect does not work (as already stated numerous times - only the https redirect works).

Comment: Well, after a lot of messing about with various rewrites and configuration, I eventually tried [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jsm-force-ssl/) which does everything necessary behind the scenes and with the `.htaccess` Strict-Transport-Security header set, HSTS eligibility passes with no errors/warnings and  can now be submitted to the browser preload list... :)

Comment: @zigojacko Happy to hear you found a solution. Feel free to answer your own question - so future visitors can see it better

Answer (score 1):

```
# Redirect to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Just tried it and it worked fine. Just remember to also set Wordpress Address and Site Address in Wordpress. I think the infinite loops "in above comments" came from that.

Always test the main url and then also one like example.com/about.html, as I have picked up sometimes that the root domain redirects well, but by having the pages added, it gives problems if redirects not done correctly.

Feel free to reply on my comment.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is struggling to get their Wordpress website (as default address https://www) to pass the [HSTS preload](https://hstspreload.org) check for subdomains so you can submit your site to the browser preload list of sites, then I eventually managed to get this resolved by using [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jsm-force-ssl/) that I referred to in [my answer above](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/319337/force-wordpress-https-redirect-before-www-redirect-based-on-site-address-url/319338?noredirect=1#comment471887_319338). This handles all https redirection across Wordpress and does it well so Wordpress can't interfere with anything.